# Pytest test collection fails with import error, though executing the test file works

Tags: python, pytest, python-import, importerror

A colleague just scrubbed our repo of large files, we all got rid of our old repos and cloned the new one.

After this happened, Pytest started failing at test collection with an import error (but just running the files as Python files does not give this import error).

Here's a simplified version of my directory structure:

```
cookiecutter_mbam
|
|__cookiecutter_mbam
|  |
|  |__ __init__.py
|  |
|  |__xnat
|     |
|     |__ __init__.py
|     | 
|     |__ tasks.py
|    
|__tests
   |
   |__ __init__.py
   |
   |__unit_tests
      |
      |__ __init__.py
      |
      |__xnat
         |
         |__ .pytest_cache
         |
         |_ __init__.py 
         |
         |_ test.py
```

When I navigate to tests/unit_tests/xnat and run `pytest test.py` I get this error:

```
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/katie/spiro/mbam/cookiecutter_mbam/tests/unit_tests/xnat/test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test.py:8: in <module>
    from cookiecutter_mbam.xnat.tasks import *
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cookiecutter_mbam'
```

Test collection works fine when I navigate over to my old repo (now in the Trash) and try it there.  I'm really struggling to see what the differences are.  The old repo has a different auto-generated pytest cache directory: `__pycache__`.  I don't know if that's a clue.

Comment: Start your tests from the project directory: `pytest tests/unittests/xnat/test.py`.

Comment: Shouldnt there be a __init__.py file for the whole module?

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks, that works!  I don't mind if I have to start my test from the project directory from now on, but do you have any idea why before I could run them in the local directory and now can't?  It's fine if you don't; it's just very curious that cleaning the repo caused this somehow.

Comment: The current working directory is automatically added to the PYTHONPATH, this way the package is found. BTW if you used the right naming conventions, the tests will be auto-discovered and a simple `pytest` is enough.

Comment: @JimTodd I don't know whether the top level is supposed to have an init file -- I guess I thought not since it's the repo directory -- but in either case both the working and the non working one lack the top level file.